# express js response.send(data) giving veracode static scan high priority issue.any thoughts to fix this issue

Tags: node.js

```
//response.send(data) giving veracode static scan high priority issue.

function(req, res) {

    acl.findOne({
        _id: new ObjectID(req.params.id)
    }, function(err, data) {
        if (err) {
            res.send({
                "message": err.message,
                "severity": "error"
            });
        }

        res.send(data);
    });
};
```

Please let me know the code fix at `res.send(data)` to resolve Veracode criss site scripting issue

Comment: got any response. Veracode throws flaws with express declaration